# Update view count, most reliable way

Tags: php, mysql, view

Hello again Stackoverflow!

I'm currently working on custom forumsoftware and one of the things you like to see on a forum is a viewcounter.

All the approaches for a viewcounter that I found would just select the topic from the database, retrieve the number from a "views" column, add one and update it.

But here's my thought: If, lets say 400, people at the exact same time open a topic, the MySQL database probably won´t count all views because it takes time for the queries to complete, and so the last person (of the 400) might overwrites the first persons (of the 400) view.

Ofcourse one could argue that on a normal site this is never going to happen, but if you have ~7 people opening that topic at the exact same second and the server is struggleing at that moment, you could have the same problem.

Is there any other good approach to count views?

**EDIT**

Woah, could the one who voted down specify why?

I ment by "Retrieving the number of views and adding one" that I would use `SELECT` to retrieve the number, add one using PHP (note the tags) and updating it using `UPDATE`. I had no idea of the other methods specified below, that's why I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So something like that will work:

```
UPDATE tbl SET cnt = cnt+1 WHERE ...
```

`UPDATE` is guaranteed to be atomic. That means no one will be able to alter `cnt` between the time it is read and the time it is replaced. If you have several concurrent `UPDATE` for the same row (InnoDB) or table (MyISAM) they have to wait their turn to update the date.

See [Is incrementing a field in MySQL atomic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358732/is-incrementing-a-field-in-mysql-atomic)

and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html

Answer (score 2):

If, lets say 400, people at the exact same time open a topic, the MySQL database **apparently would count all the views** because this is exactly what databases were invented for.

All the approaches for a viewcounter that you have found are wrong. To update a field you don't need to retrieve it, but just already update:

```
UPDATE forum SET views + 1 WHERE id = ?
```

Comment: Now is my question, how?

Comment: Up date the views entry in the database before the page is displayed. `UPDATE \`views_table\` SET \`views\` = \`views\` + 1 WHERE \`post_id\` = '$post_id' LIMIT 1;`