# MySQL deadlock possible?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, deadlock

I have a java app running on MySQL, Hibernate, and Spring-managed transactions.
There's one specific transaction that worries me a little. I tried to set up some concurrent testing environment (using [ApacheBench](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html)), tests seem ok, but I still have some doubts...
Transaction logic is along these lines (using mixed sql + pseudo-code, for brevity):

```
updated = 0;

// lock counter row, if exists
selected = select x from tbl1 where [composite PK match] FOR UPDATE;

if(selected == null) {
    // Record does not exist... I thought this might be a good idea, as there will be only 
    // one insert for the given PK daily and many subsequent updates (rather do this than 
    // forcing 'insert...on duplicate key update' constantly?)
    updated = insert into tbl1 values(...) on duplicate key update cnt = cnt + 1;
} else {
    // Record exists, just increment the counter.
    updated = update tbl1 set cnt = cnt + 1;
}
return updated;
```

Table `tbl1` is like this:

```
create table tbl1 (
  `a_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `b_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `c_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `day` date NOT NULL,
  `cnt` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`a_id`,`b_id`,`c_id`,`day`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Transaction isolation is MySQL's default (`REPEATABLE READ`).

The most important concern for me is:

1. Is the above code valid candidate to cause deadlocks in a highly concurrent environment?

...and I'd also like to add two related sub-questions:

2. Is incrementing a counter on this single table: `update tbl1 set c = c + 1 where [match row by composite PK]` thread-safe / atomic / consistent ?
   According to my tests, it is. According to [the existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358732/is-incrementing-a-field-in-mysql-atomic), it may depend... and if it is, I guess the above logic can be further optimized/simplified so it does not use `select...for update` (I added it just to be on the safe side).
3. If `select...where...for update` is executed within a transaction as a very first statement, but no record matched `WHERE` clause, can this possibly cause some hidden row-level locking before subsequent DML statements may be executed with the same matching condition (as in the example), and how this may affect other concurrent transactions?